# Referencing Azure Key Vault secrets from CI/CD YAML

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-yaml-pipelines

We have a multi-stage YAML pipeline that does CI/CD to an existing set of Azure Resources

The stages are

1. Build
2. Deploy to Development and Run Tests
3. If Previous succeeded - Deploy to Production and Run Tests

We use the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task during the deployment stages and we use the AppSettings argument to that task to specify environment-specific settings. For example

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
      displayName: 'Deploy Azure App Service'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscriptionEndpoint)'
        appType: '$(webAppKind)'
        WebAppName: 'EXISTING__AZURE_RESOURCENAME-DEV'
        Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
        AppSettings: >
          -AzureAd:CallbackPath /signin-oidc
          -AzureAd:ClientId [GUID was here]
          -AzureAd:Domain [domain was here]
          -AzureAd:Instance https://login.microsoftonline.com/ 
          -AzureAd:TenantId [Id was here]
          -EmailServer:SMTPPassword SECRETPASSWORD
          -EmailServer:SMTPUsername SECRETUSERNAME
```

There are two settings in that set, `EmailServer: SMTPUsername` and `EmailServer: SMTPPassword` that I want to pull from an Azure KeyVault. I know how to reference the KV secret from Azure Portal using the syntax

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://our.vault.azure.net/secrets/SendGridPassword/ReferenceGuidHere)
```

but how do I reference the value from the YAML pipeline so it is set in Azure?

Comment: Do you want to reference the `@Microsoft.KeyVault(...)` in your pipeline or inject the key vault value directly ?

Comment: I just want to ensure that the appsettings are set correctly so that at run time of the App Service it will evaluate that KeyVault reference

Comment: you shoule be able to do something like that in your pipeline `-EmailServer:SMTPPassword "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://our.vault.azure.net/secrets/SendGridPassword/ReferenceGuidHere)"`

Comment: That's what I am trying  right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Thomas in this comment, [Referencing Azure Key Vault secrets from CI/CD YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992469/referencing-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-ci-cd-yaml#comment-113158548)

I can explicitly set the value in the YAML file like this:

```
-EmailServer:SMTPPassword @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://our.vault.azure.net/secrets/SendGridPassword/ReferenceGuidHere)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an AzureKeyVault@1 task with RunAsPreJob to true, this will make your key vault values available as CI/CD jobs environment variables so you can use it as $(KEY-OF-SECRET-VALUE) on the rest of your stages in the job.

The following piece of yaml file is a working example.
We set for python unittest a set of env variable provided from Azure key-vault

```
trigger:
  batch: true # disable concurrent build for pipeline
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'  # CI start for all branches

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-16.04

stages:

- stage: Test
  jobs:
  - job: sample_test_stage
    steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'YOUR SUBSCRIPTION HERE'
        KeyVaultName: 'THE-KEY-VAULT-NAME'
        SecretsFilter: '*'
        RunAsPreJob: true
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.7'
    - script : python -m unittest discover -v -s tests
      displayName: 'Execute python unittest'
      env: { MY-ENV-VAL-1: $(SECRET-VALUE-1), MY-ENV-VAL-2: $(SECRET-VALUE-2)}
```

Note that sometimes you need to approve connection beetween AzureDevops and another Azure service like KeyVault

Comment: because I only want to be able to set the value of the AppSettings as discused with Thomas in his comments I can literally copy the reference into my YAML