# How to pass the secret from azure key vault to Environmental variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-release-task

The environmental variable **TEST_SECRETS** shall contain the secrets from the azure key vault.
This can be achieved by the AzureKeyVault task shown as follow

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
          displayName: Credential Fetch
          inputs:
            connectedServiceName: 'KVfetch'
            KeyVaultName: 'kv_abc_devops'
            SecretsFilter: 'db-primarykey-dev'
            RunAsPreJob: true
```

How can I pass the value of **db-primarykey-dev** to **TEST_SECRETS**

can I use variables as follows?

```
variables:
- name: TEST_SECRET
  value: $db-primarykey-dev
```

I try to pass the variable right before the test it does not work

```
- task: CmdLine@2
          displayName: Integration Tests
        - script: |
            echo 'TEST_SECRET = $db-primarykey-dev'
            pytest test/integration --verbose -s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using env mapping:

```yaml
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Integration Tests
- script: |
    pytest test/integration --verbose -s
  env:
    TEST_SECRET: $(db-primarykey-dev)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also  please check and try by specifying the azureSubscription field under **inputs** of azurekeyvault task  if it makes difference byreplacing Connected service name or by including as additional parameter:

```
azureSubscription: 'YOUR SUBSCRIPTION HERE'
```

Try with > echo $(TEST_SECRET) .
See this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#:%7E:text=version%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20echo%20%24(skipMe)-,echo%20%24(StageSauce),-The%20output%20from) for reference.
See if you are missing inputs tag in

```
- task: CmdLine@2 
  displayName: Integration Tests
     inputs: 
        script: echo $(TEST_SECRET)
```

See the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=%2D%20task%3A%20CmdLine%402%0A%20%20inputs%3A%0A%20%20%20%20script%3A%20%27echo%20%24(Your%2DSecret%2DName)%20%3E%20secret.txt%27).
Also we can do [environment mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992469/referencing-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-ci-cd-yaml) as said by @Krzysztof Madej